# Create an exception-safe wrapper of a class

Tags: java, exception

I have a legacy class C1, implementing interface I, that may throw some exceptions.

I want to create a class C2, also implementing interface I, that is based on an instance of C1, but catches all exceptions and does something useful about them.

Currently my implementation looks like this:

```
class C2 implements I {
    C1 base;

    @Override void func1() {
      try {
         base.func1();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         doSomething(e);
      }
    }

    @Override void func2() {
      try {
         base.func2();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         doSomething(e);
      }
    }

    ...

}
```

(Note: I could also make C2 extend C1. This does not matter for the current question).

The interface contains many functions, so I have to write the same try... catch block again and again.

Is there a way to reduce the amount of code duplication here?

Comment: the methods you wanna "wrap" are purely from the interface or there are additional ones? Because it is not clear since you are overriding some package visible methods in your sample.

Comment: Not if you want to have plain java source for C2.

Comment: @Java Mentor What difference does it make?

Comment: if it is just from the interface a proxy would be ok, if not you need to take inheritance approach

Comment: What do you mean by "inheritance approach"?

Comment: inherit the class and override the method calling super within try-catch, its different than interface implementation that is more or less just a decorator, what would expose just the methods present on the interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a Proxy, it could actually be generic

```
interface I1 {
    void test();
}

class C1 implements I1 {
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("test");
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}

class ExceptionHandler implements InvocationHandler {
    Object obj;

    ExceptionHandler(Object obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        try {
            return method.invoke(obj, args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // need a workaround for primitive return types
            return null;
        }
    }

    static <T> T proxyFor(Object obj, Class<T> i) {
        return (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(obj.getClass().getClassLoader(), new Class[] { i },
                new ExceptionHandler(obj));
    }
}

public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        I1 i1 = ExceptionHandler.proxyFor(new C1(), I1.class);
        i1.test();
    }
}
```